# WPF - MVVM - Conditionally include user controls to view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, conditional-statements

In WPF my MVVM application I need to create an account search view with 2 options simple search by account # or Advanced search (by name, email, etc.)

In my AccountSearchViewModel I have a bool property IsAdvancedMode.

Also I have created 2 UserControls for each mode: SimpleSearchView and AdvancedSearchView

Now I need to show either one based on IsAdvancedMode property.

What is the best way to do it?

Also as a general solution what if I have SearchMode property that is enum. How whould you switch between multiple controls in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually drop them both and then use the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).  Simplest approach with what you've got set up.

```
<Grid>
  <SimpleSearch />
  <AdvancedSearch 
          Visibility="{Binding IsAdvancedMode, Converter={StaticResource btvc}"/>
</Grid>
```

When `IsAdvancedMode` is `true`, the AdvancedSearch control will overlay the SimpleSearch.  Again, this is the **simplest approach**, not necessarily the absolute best.

Comment: I must agree this is not best way - more like a hack but it worked for me and I was needed solution to my problem asap.

Comment: @MichaelD.: I wouldn't be so harsh as to call it a hack.  Overlaying one UI element over another is an old practice.  Not one that should be done for security purposes, of course.  If it concerns you, it is extremely simple to create an `InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Comment: this continues to affect the controls dimensions, so yea its not the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to use [Data Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), to do that you need to create three classes:

```
     public class Search
        {
            //Your Code
        }

        public class AdvanceSearch : Search
        {
           //Your Code
        }

        public class SimpleSearch : Search
        {
          //Your Code
        }
```

and then create Data Template base on Classes:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AdvanceSearch }">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Email}"/>    
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SimpleSearch }">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />    
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Not good... I want to bind to a property in my ViewModel so User can switch between views. Also my advance search is more complicated - it is actually query builder sort of thing that why I need it in control of its own

Comment: The Search owner class will have Search property which will be instantiated based on the user switch between different search types. you can implement all of you Query builder code inside advance search class.

Comment: @MichaelD.: This is the *one true answer*.  You should consider doing this.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a DataTrigger to swap out the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentControl` as needed. I wrote an article about switching Views in MVVM [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if you're interested (examples included)

Here's some quick test code demonstrating it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA" >
        <TextBlock Text="I'm Template A" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateB" >
        <TextBlock Text="I'm Template B" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Test" Content="Test" />

    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateB}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Well - I did exactly what you suggested but my view shows following:System.Windows.DataTemplate instead of rendering the content of the template. What would be the problem?

Comment: @Michael Are you altering the `ContentTemplate` property and not the `Template` property? It sounds like it is encountering a DataTemplate object as the Content, so rendering it using the default `ToString()` method.

Comment: I have just copied whole code from your blog. It alters "ContentTemplate". I have posted a comment with my code to your blog post.

Comment: @Michael The code didn't post in the comment. Can you post it here? I did a quick test of the code and it executes fine. I also altered my  Answer to show the Sample code I used.

Comment: I added another comment to your post - with the code at this time. please check it out.

Comment: @Michael The problem is you're setting your ContentControl.Content to a DataTemplate. The DataTemplate was meant to go in the Resources, and your code to display it is simply `<ContentControl Content="{Binding AccountSearchViewModel}"/>`. Or you can remove the `DataTemplate` wrapper and just use the ContentControl - I only had it there because I like my UserControl content neat and tidy :)